# Updating the name of the menu item dynamically upon click

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to have the menu item name as "Show" initially and toggle the name of the menuitem to "Hide" when click, and toggle back to "Show" again when click again. It is not working. Please advice. thanks

```
private void StatisticsFunctionsShowOrHideMenu_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem m = sender as MenuItem;
    if (m != null)
    {
        m.Name = m.Name == "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show";
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to update Haeder value rather than Name.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 'Name' with 'Text'.

```
private void StatisticsFunctionsShowOrHideMenu_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
    MenuItem m = sender as MenuItem; 
    if (m != null) {
        m.Text = m.Text == "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show"; 
    } 
}
```